# JQuery For Loop animation

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

Simply put, using Canvas I would like to draw 10 rectangles each with their own identifier.
Here is what I have, which is completely wrong I know:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        var b = new Box();
        context.drawImage(b, i*20,20);
    }
});

function Box() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = 10;
    this.height = 10;
    this.fill = '#444444';
}
```

The reason I want to give each one an ID is so I can control the height of each one via an xml document
Really appreciate your help!

Comment: where are the images you want to draw using `drawImage`? You question is unclear. You can edit and add more detail

Answer (score 1):

I think you should store your 'Box' elements inside an array, and use a function to redraw the canvas each time one of the box change:

```
var boxes = [];
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

$(document).ready(function(){
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        boxes.push(new Box());
    }
    refreshCanvas();
});

function refreshCanvas()
{
    // -- Clear canvas:
    context .clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // -- Draw boxes:
    for(i=0; i<boxes.length; i++){
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, boxes[i].width, boxes[i].height);
        context.stroke();
    }
}

function Box() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = 10;
    this.height = 10;
    this.fill = '#444444';
}
```

Then, each time you modify one of your boxes, you just have to call refreshCanvas.

Comment: Many thanks for this although it's not successfully pushing anything into the array, although the Box() method is being called.
Thanks for your patience - I'm so new to this

Comment: There was a uneeded space between 'boxes' and '.push' and '[]' was use instaed of '()'. I fix my answer, be sure to do the same and it should work.

Comment: Actually, I also fixed some other issues. Please update your code completly.

Comment: Thanks for that! Yeah I noticed the syntax actually. That's great - works now. Thank you

Comment: Ok great :) Please mark my answer as accepted by checking the grey box below vote count. This way people will know that this is the right solution. Thx.

Comment: +1 Nice answer.  In your for-loop, you might consider var box=boxes[i] and then context.rect(box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height)